# Difference between running Java from command line with file ending and without

Tags: java, command-line

I just wrote a simple hello world class called `Hello`:

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

The "normal" way to run it from the command line as far as I know is

1) compiling it (and creating the file `Hello.class`):

```
javac Hello.java
```

2) running it:

```
java Hello
```

I just found out by accident that it is also possible to just invoke

```
java Hello.java
```

without creating a `Hello.class` file first!
This also does not crate an own class file..

*So now, I am asking myself, what exactly happens, when I just run `java Hello.java`?*

Comment: As this could depend on the Java version, which version and distribution are you using? And you said you could call `java Hello.java` - did it run as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

See [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) describing this new feature in [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) 11 and later, where `java MyClass.java` will both compile and run a single-file of source code.

## Java 11

You have found a new feature in Java 11 implementations built on [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) 11.  For convenience, a single `.java` file can now be compiled *and* executed merely by calling `java` on the command line.

The `java` automatically calls on `javac` to do the compiling. The resulting compiled class is then run.

See [*JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330). To quote that JEP:

> Single-file programs -- where the whole program fits in a single source file -- are common in the early stages of learning Java, and when writing small utility programs. In this context, it is pure ceremony to have to compile the program before running it. In addition, a single source file may compile to multiple class files, which adds packaging overhead to the simple goal of "run this program". It is desirable to be able to run the program directly from source with the java launcher:
>
> `java HelloWorld.java`

And, yes, this simple feature should have been built decades ago to help countless beginners trying to learn Java.

---

Caveat: A Java implementation *not* built from the OpenJDK source-code may or may not include such a feature. That is the difference between a [JEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Enhancement_Proposal) ([OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) only) and a [JSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) (defined in [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)).

Answer (score 2):

With JDK 11 you can launch [Single-File Source-Code Programs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) with the interpreter. This won't work if you have multiple files scattered in the directory.